# Angular - How to always get the newest data at localStorage?

Tags: angular, web-services, local-storage

I know that there is a lot of questions on SO talking about this issue, but until now I didn't find any topic that could solve this problem. Basically, I have a service responsible for get data from service and save locally and a component to show this data. But every time I send a new request the component show the old data instead of the new. I already tried to:

```
localStorage.removeItem(this.dataToShow);
localStorage.setItem(this.dataToShow, JSON.stringify(content));
```

But even this solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well you need the component data updated by the time the local storage value updated. Ya ?**

In Angular there is no binding to local storage. In other words you have to get item value from local storage every time it is updated.

So I suggest you to import the service and subscribe to a subject so any change can be propagate to component.

so In your service call Subject.next() to send message to observable.
so the subscribe will be notified.

Here is a help full link.
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: I'm using `subscribe` method bus still getting same issue.

Comment: Did you use subject ?  How about subject.next() ? 

Plz refer the link.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i could understand you want to show the data stored locally first you need to save the data locally like that 
localStorage.setItem('mean-token', token); mean-token is the name and token is the object and you can call the object by the name :
const name = localStorage.getItem('mean-token'); and to remove it you can use :
localStorage.removeItem('mean-token')
hope thats work if not  can u explain the probleme better

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [**ngx-webstorage-service**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage-service)

You'll need to initialize an **Observable** method which returns a **Subject** variable to track changes in your Local Storage service.

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage-service';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// Key used to access status in local storage
const STATUS_STORAGE_KEY = 'status_test';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
  private storageStatus = new Subject<string>();
  constructor (
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE)
    private storage: StorageService)
  {}

  watchStorage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.storageStatus.asObservable();
  }

  // Set Method
  public setStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.storage.set(STATUS_STORAGE_KEY, status);
    this.storageStatus.next('changed'); // tell subscribers storage status is updated
  }

  // Get Method
  public getStatus() {
    return this.storage.get(STATUS_STORAGE_KEY);
  }
}
```

**In your component.ts**

Setting new data into local storage will trigger the **Behavior** variable and subscribers will then be notified that changes are made

```
this.localStorage.setStatus(true);
```

Subscribe to the observable so that whenever the storage has new data added in, it will be updated as well.

```
this.localStorage.watchStorage().subscribe(() => {
  this.updatedStatus = this.localStorage.getStatus();
})
```